# Undoing a downvote

Tags: support, feature-request, down-votes

I'm sure this has come up before, but a cursory search of meta didn't turn up anything relevant. On occasion I have downvoted an answer, but then the author edited it and I felt that it didn't deserve the downvote any longer. However on a few occasions, I felt that though a downvote was no longer warranted, I still didn't want to upvote the answer. However, when I click on the appropriate arrows on the left, after having downvoted an answer, the only thing I seem to be able to do is convert the downvote to an upvote as opposed to converting it to "no vote." Is there a way to do this, or is this something on SE's radar?

Comment: I think you can undo the vote by making a trivial edit to the post to reset the undo timer.

Comment: @Qiaochu: That seems like it could be a good workaround, except then I get my name associated with the post as an editor. Could be worse I guess.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I did a quick experiment on 5 previous questions that I previously voted on, but have since been edited (surprisingly easy to find, actually). Simply clicking on the arrow of my vote successfully removed my vote. So if I had downvoted, I clicked on the downvote arrow and it went away. Upvote - I clicked on the upvote and it went away.

I then put them back, by the way.

Does that not work for you?

Comment: I'm going to try on this answer.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to work. I was clicking on the uparrow not the downarrow. My thinking was that the uparrow should increase the tally by 1, but I see I was wrong.

Comment: @Jim: Lol, thinking the +1 button would undo the -1 button. You'd think that would work, this being a math site and all. (Also: up and downvotes confer asymmetric rep displacement.)